# how could i send parameters to create my data in Open Flash Chart?

Tags: php, flash

I am trying to send parameters to my data file to full my open flash chart... according of this framework, it sends like parameter a .php file to a .swf , still, that .php file does not receive parametes, its only called by the .swf so it does let me catch the url or some other parameter, i have no idea how to do this, how could i send more parameters to a .php file that is called through a swf??

here is the link of open flash chart
http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart/index.php

Any other chart framework easy to use for php?

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert the path to your file to the encodeURIComponent(); ...It worked for me ;)

```
var path = encodeURIComponent(./path/to/your/file.php?param1=x&param2=y);
swfobject.embedSWF("./open-flash-chart.swf", "my_chart", "400", "250", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf", {"data-file": path } );
```